# Cluster Servers - ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, cluster-computing

What kind of hardware do I need to handle a cluster between 3 servers? 
Can this be done programatically?

What changes do I need to do on my ASP.NET MVC Site?

Comment: Can what be done programmatically? Building a server?

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, it has nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC.. If you're seeking an easy way to scale your application then you could try Azure platform, otherwise you go to [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/) for more info on how to set up a cluster.